# Footer always on bottom with "flexbox" (Issue on IE 11)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flexbox

Im testing some features of the flexbox. So, i tried to put the footer of the web on the bottom with flex.

This is the test, and code (Test it With IE to see the issue):
https://jsfiddle.net/3bcw8zL2/

**The html:**

```
<body>
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>

<main>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p> 
  
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  
</main>
</body>

<footer>
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</footer>
```

**The Css:**

```
  body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

header, footer {
  background: #ccc;
  h1 {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

And works perfect with Chrome and Mozilla, but with IE 11 the footer keeps just right down of the content. And this is pissing me off.

Can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `height: 100vh;` to the body-tag in your CSS.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neh725sz/1/

Comment: Thanks so much, that really worked. Why IE doesn't support the min-height? If you can explain me i'll appreciate it.

Comment: I have another problem, now. When the content is too much Chrome doesn't show it right. You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/neh725sz/2/ (Only happens with Chrome).

Comment: I'm really not sure why, but seems IE doesn't respect min-height. (Source: http://snipplr.com/view/57936/). From that same source you'll find an even better way to go about it, adding _height: 100vh; instead. That way you should target IE only. :) Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neh725sz/3/